# Forum Software Suitable For The Modern Web

Tags: mobile, forum, responsive-webdesign

I know that forums are in no way as popular as they used to be, but I always wanted to set one up, and still do, so I'm really considering my options.

Let me outline what I'm after.

I preferably want (meaning I actually want) a free open source forum, which can be customised to suit what I want. I think PHPBB may be the one to go for, but I'm open to suggestions.

The next, and main issue is that I need a site that is going to work on a desktop and a mobile. Now I'm not particuarly bothered about it being scalable to 300px, but a 480px would be great, as long as I can use `Meta Viewport` to shrink it down slightly for mobile phones.

Lastly, I would really be relying on Advertising, so a theme which allows adsense to be placed in there would be fantastic.

Any ideas on the best Software and Themes to use for the modern web? Do you know any examples of existing forums that work well on desktop and mobile?

Any advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: Muscletalk.co.za - phpbb

Comment: Platinumwealth.co.za - mybb

Comment: Mybroadband.co.za/vb - vbulliton

Comment: Thanks @ErikThiart. The PHPBB is a little too flat but it's a nice example of a cheap forum. Do you know of anything similar to the `Mybroadband.co.za/vb` website on PHPBB?

Comment: Not on phpbb that's unique to vbulliton